# qtcreator says file not found in issues list

Tags: qt-creator

This problem seems annoyingly intermittent. Sometimes I'll build a project and all the errors in the issues list say "file not found". I've triple checked the file exists. The make command prints an error for a relative path and both the "working directory" and the "build directory" plus the relative file path exists yet qtcreator says it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the file has to be part of the qtcreator project. This often happens right after a new file has been created externally to qtcreator. To fix, right click on the project, choose "edit files" and add the new files.